# Looking for the .NET or iOS equivilant of SetConcat for Matrix Concatonation

Tags: android, ios, matrix

I'm working on a system that is detecting multi-touch at two points and then handling zoom and pan concurrently within the one gesture.

I'm using the `Matrix` class on `Android` to perform the Concatonations and that is working exactly as I expected.

The Android work is executing the following code that is using the transformations:

```
Matrix pivotFrom = new Matrix ();
pivotFrom.SetTranslate (-pivot0_x, -pivot0_y);
Matrix pivotTo = new Matrix ();
pivotTo.SetTranslate (pivot0_x, pivot0_y);
Matrix scaleMat = new Matrix ();
scaleMat.SetScale (scale, scale);
Matrix pivotToCurrent = new Matrix ();
pivotToCurrent.SetTranslate (pivot1_x, pivot1_y);

Matrix tt = new Matrix ();

tt.SetConcat (scaleMat, pivotFrom);
tt.SetConcat (pivotToCurrent, tt);

_currentMatrix.SetConcat (tt, _startMatrix);
```

This is working fine for `Android` which is great, but I'm finding that moving it to `iOS` the `Matrix` class in `.NET` from `System.Drawing2D` does not have the `SetConcat` method. I'm thinking maybe there is a mechanism that I could use as a replacement to get this to work. I also have access to a `CGAffineTransform` reference as part of the `IOS Matrix` implementation so if you know that equivalent there that could help.

Any help is appreciated, my `Matrix` math is beyond rusty.